# ImportError with Transformers and Accelerate in Google Colab: Seq2SeqTrainingArguments not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I'm facing an ImportError when trying to use the Seq2SeqTrainingArguments class from the transformers library with accelerate in Google Colab.This is the error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-90ef02e6f0d8> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments
      2 
----> 3 training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
      4     output_dir="whisper",  # change to a repo name of your choice
      5     per_device_train_batch_size=16,

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py in _setup_devices(self)
   1729         if not is_sagemaker_mp_enabled():
   1730             if not is_accelerate_available(min_version="0.20.1"):
-> 1731                 raise ImportError(
   1732                     "Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U`"
   1733                 )
```

**Environment:**

Google Colab
Python 3.10
CUDA version 11.8

I try to do the following, but i still got the same error:

```
!pip install accelerate>=0.20.1
!pip install torch torchvision torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
!pip install transformers
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall the existing installations of `accelerate` and `transformers`:

`!pip uninstall accelerate transformers`

2. Reinstall the required versions of `accelerate` and `transformers`:

`!pip install accelerate>=0.20.3 transformers`

3. Restart the runtime to apply the changes: Go to the "Runtime" menu at the top of the Colab interface and choose "Restart Runtime."

Now, you should be able to use the Seq2SeqTrainingArguments class without encountering the ImportError.